# How to concatenate files from different sub-directories?

Tags: find, cat, merge

I have a large folder containing many sub-directories each holding many `.txt` files. I want to concatenate all of these files into one `.txt` file. I am able to do it for each of the sub-directories with `cat *.txt>merged.txt`, but I am trying to do it for all of the files in the large folder. How do I do this?

Answer (score 13):

try with

```
find /path/to/source -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} + >mergedfile
```

find all '*.txt' `f`iles in `/path/to/source` recursively for sub-directories and concatenate all into one `mergedfile`.

To concatenate each sub-directories files within its directory, do:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -execdir sh -c 'cat $1/*.txt >> $1/mergedfile' _ {} \;
```

Comment: `>>` can be `>` in the first `find` call.

Comment: @Kusalananda won't that truncate the mergedfile if ARG_MAX exceed?

Comment: The `>` redirects the output of `find`, not `cat`.  The `cat` command ends at the `+`, and you can't do redirections in `-exec` without using a child shell (`sh -c`).  In your second example, you won't need it either as you do one directory at a time.

Comment: Actually, that second example won't work. Since `-execdir` is already executing with the directory as the working directory, you should get rid of `$1/` in the command.

Comment: @Kusalananda your first point about using `>` instead of `>>` in first command is right but `$1/` is needed in second command and that works I tested before. note that execdir is changing for the find not for the child-shell I used there

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely correct. I didn't notice you were searching for _directories_!

Comment: What is the purpose of the underscore (`_`) that appears just before the the opening and closing braces (`{}`)?

Comment: @DerekMahar That is used as a placeholder for the used inline-shell command's "zeroth" argument or $0, which is usually represent the name of the shell or script being executed. so if any failure reported, it will be reported with that name. you can use any other name instead of `_` there.

Comment: @αғsнιη, why does the command not work if I remove the underscore parameter?  More specifically, why can't the first argument to `sh` be `{}` which is the placeholder that `find` replaces with each directory name?

Comment: @DerekMahar `_` there is 0th argument to the `sh -c '....'` and `{}` is the 1st. when you remove the `_`, the `{}` is being 0th argument while the `sh -c '...'` perform and do stuff on the `$1` argument but now there is no 1st (`$1`) argument. why we don't use the `{}` as the first argument because in general always the 1st argument is the script name and all errors/warning/... will use that  name prefixed to alert where things go wrong.

Comment: @αғsнιη, thank you for the explanation.  I think I understand the purpose of the 0th argument.  When you invoke a named shell script, `$0` is always the name of the script, but in this case, the script is anonymous, so you must provide the name of the script as the first (0th) argument.  Is this correct?

Comment: Example: `sh -c 'echo $0 $1 $2' a b c` prints `a b c` and `sh -c 'echo $1 $2' a b c` prints `b c`.  In both cases, `sh` assigns `a` to `$0`, `b` to `$1`, and `c` to `$2`, but only the first example prints all of the arguments.

Comment: @DerekMahar yes. all passed arguments to the script in both cases are available. it depends if you want to use/print them or not. in second example 0th argument is also available to the script but you didn't print it doesn't mean it's not available.

Comment: Ran into the issue that the file itself was added over and over again because I used the current directory for search and output. Maybe it also helps others: `find ./ -type f -name '*.txt' -not -name 'mergedfile.txt' -exec cat {} + >mergedfile.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bash and the number of text files is contained (i.e. does not exceed the maximum argument number limit, which is very large but not infinite), you can easily achieve this with the `globstar` feature:

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ cat **/*.txt > merged.txt
```

A more general, although less elegant approach, will be to use `find` as the driver and make it call `cat` on each file, appending the output:

```
$ find -name \*.txt -exec sh -c 'cat {} >> merged.out' \;
```

Calling `sh` is needed here because you want to append the result of each `cat`. Make sure the output file has a different extension or lies outside of the tree you're merging, or `find` may try to concatenate the output with itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do the concatenation in a particular order, then the below will concatenate the files in lexicographical order (sorted by pathnames) in `bash`:

```
shopt -s globstar
for name in **/*.txt; do
    [ -f "$name" ] && cat <"$name"
done >merged.out
```

This is similar to the `find` command

```
find  . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec cat {} ';' >merged.out
```

except that the ordering may be different, symbolic links to regular files would be included (add a `&& [ ! -L "$name" ]` if you don't want them) and  hidden files (and files in hidden directories) would be excluded (use `shopt -s dotglob` to add them back).

Comment: what else your first command does that the same in my answer doesn't?

Comment: @αғsнιη Absolutely nothing now when you've changed your answer. I will modify that part. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Does bash guarantee that `**/*.txt` sorts the pathnames in lexicographical order?

Comment: @DerekMahar Yes, the list resulting from expanding a globbing pattern is guaranteed to be lexicographically sorted. From the POSIX standard: "If the pattern matches any existing filenames or pathnames, the pattern shall be replaced with those filenames and pathnames, sorted according to the collating sequence in effect in the current locale."