# How to group files from find command into a single line where each file is inside double quotes?

Tags: shell, find, freebsd, xargs

This is a recurrent issue I have always had while dealing with iterations or actions over files found using find.

I have the following files:

```
 $ find . -name "*ES 03-11*" 
./01jan/ES 03-11.txt
./02feb/ES 03-11.txt
./03mar/ES 03-11.txt
./04apr/ES 03-11.txt
./05may/ES 03-11.txt
```

And I would like to launch the following command:

```
$ cat "./01jan/ES 03-11.txt" "./02feb/ES 03-11.txt" "./03mar/ES 03-11.txt" "./04apr/ES 03-11.txt" "./05may/ES 03-11.txt" | process
```

Which means concatenating each line provided by find but enclosed into double quotes or simple quotes I guess.

I have tried this:

```
find . -name "*ES 03-11*" | awk '{printf "\"%s\" ", $0}' | xargs cat | process
```

Which seems to work, but I am wondering if there is any other way to do it without using awk or doing something easy to remember or type.

I am using FreeBSD and Bourne Shell.

Comment: Have you tried `find . -name "*ES 03-11*" -exec cat {} +`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate files from different sub-directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447702/how-to-concatenate-files-from-different-sub-directories) Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/292253

Comment: @iruvar what does the + mean?

Comment: @M.E. see the `-exec utility [argument ...] {} +` section at the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize you can use the `-exec` method:

```
find . -name "*ES 03-11*" -exec cat {} +
```

or an `xargs` approach:

```
find . -name "*ES 03-11*" | xargs -I xx cat xx
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the NULL-termination features are for. Unfortunately although `find -print0` exists, the `xargs` command on FreeBSD seems not to have the matching `-0`. This precludes `xargs` as part of any solution.

Another solution is to iterate across your pattern

```
for file in */*'ES 03-11'*; do cat "$file"; done | process
```

Or, for many files,

```
for dir in *
do
    [ -d "$dir" ] || continue
    for file in "$dir"/*'ES 03-11'*
    do
        [ -f "$file" ] && cat "$file"
    done
done | process
```

Or even directly

```
cat */*'ES 03-11'* | process
```